# How to dynamically modify an API response

Tags: javascript, json, api, web

I have an API that I am using however to get it to display I'm using:

`` `<div>${JSON.stringify(response)}</div> ` ``

to get the the API endpoint to display and this works fine.
However this results in an output like

`{xxx:more text here}`

The thing is I only want the more text here to be displayed so I use response.xxx and this works however how do I dynamically change the xxx in java script. So with a button click or some such action I can change the xxx so on the button click response.xxx can become response.yyy.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Option one have a variable to hold the key value, and then do ```response[value]``` where you can set the ```value='xxx' or value='yyy'``` or anything else as required. If there are multiple keys in the response and you want only the values, then use ```Object.values(response)``` to fetch all values as an array. If you want the values one at a time, use ```Object.keys(response)``` and fetch all keys as array and use it to iterate over response. All this action can be bound to a click event of a button and update the div text as wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Building on what was said by [gvmani](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1825844/gvmani) simply add a place holder value to the response thus:

`<div>${JSON.stringify(response)}</div>`

becomes:

`<div>${JSON.stringify(response[xxx])}</div>`

where I can change the value of xxx to any other as needed.